# arm-none-eabi-g++ can't find cc1plus unless run from gdb?

Tags: c++, compiler, arm7

I am trying to port some simple c++ code to armv7e-m. I have experience compiling c++ for arm but this is my first time setting up the toolchain from scratch. Initially, I was having the following error:

[image]

This despite having the containing folder of cc1plus in my PATH:

`~/arm-gnu-toolchain-12.2.rel1-x86_64-arm-none-eabi/bin/:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin:/snap/bin:~/arm-gnu-toolchain-12.2.rel1-x86_64-arm-none-eabi/libexec/gcc/arm-none-eabi/12.2.1`

It's in the last one, under libexec/gcc/... I feel that I should not have had to add this path manually anyway. In any case, that didn't work... *except when I ran it in gdb???*

`gdb --args arm-none-eabi-g++ -march=armv7e-m -w -c tetris.cpp`

`start`

`c`

*normal exit*

`arm-none-eabi-size tetris.o`

`tetris.o: ELF 32-bit LSB relocatable, ARM, EABI5 version 1 (SYSV), not stripped`

My suspicion is that there's some environment variable shenanigans going on here. That doesn't make much sense though, since execvp is not the version that overwrites environ, that would be execve?

My compiler is `arm-none-eabi-g++ (Arm GNU Toolchain 12.2.Rel1 (Build arm-12.24)) 12.2.1 20221205` which I got already built for Linux off of Arm's website. I'm running Ubuntu 22.04.2.

EDIT: I have narrowed down what's going on.

The following works:

`~/arm-gnu-toolchain-12.2.rel1-x86_64-arm-none-eabi/bin/arm-none-eabi-g++ -c -g3 -Og -ffunction-sections -march=armv7e-m -mcpu=cortex-m4 -o tetris.o src/tetris.cpp`

This does not:

`arm-none-eabi-g++ -c -g3 -Og -ffunction-sections -march=armv7e-m -mcpu=cortex-m4 -o tetris.o src/tetris.cpp`

PATH is set in both cases to point to both g++ and cc1plus. I have made sure there is no other arm-none-eabi-g++ on my system. Curiously, `which arm-none-eabi-g++` shows nothing. Is it possible something's gone extremely wrong with my linux install?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, compiler backends are not supposed to be on the path, because their names are not unique, and the frontend is not supposed to use the path for this.

Instead, the frontend is supposed to find the backends. It uses two ways for that: its own path, which it knows only from the command line, and a compiled-in value that is derived from the `--prefix` parameter the compiler was configured with.

The former is why using the full path works: the backend can be found relative to `~/arm-gnu-toolchain-12.2.rel1-x86_64-arm-none-eabi/bin/arm-none-eabi-g++`.

If you do a "traditional" installation, you'd use the default `--prefix` setting of `/usr/local` for the compiler, then either use `DESTDIR` (more reliable) or override `prefix` during installation (works with most GNU packages) to redirect it to a subtree, and then use a symlink farming tool like `stow` to make the compiler available system-wide.

To install into a directory below your home like you want, you'd need to pass `--prefix=~/arm-gnu-toolchain-12.2.rel1-x86_64-arm-none-eabi` when configuring the compiler.

Comment: Could it working when run from gdb be explained by gdb calling it with a full path internally?

Comment: Yes, that is precisely what happens. I just checked with another program, and `argv[0]` has the full path when run under gdb.